# Can i use windows phone 7 app on windows 8 app store

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

I developed almost 20 apps on windows phone 7 it also work on windows phone 8 , now i want to upload that apps in windows 8 store . Can i upload all my apps on windows 8 app store or i have to made some changes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

> Can i upload all my apps on windows 8 app store ... ?

No, you have to convert your App because the .NET Frameworks used by WP7 and WinRT are different.

Take a look at "Migrating a Windows Phone 7 app to XAML" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465136%28v=VS.85%29.aspx :

Porting a Microsoft Silverlight app for Windows Phone to a Windows Store app built for Windows using C++, C#, or Visual Basic is relatively easy to do, although it does present some challenges. Most of your knowledge and experience will transfer to the model for Windows Store apps using XAML, as will much of your XAML UI design.

Your app-porting effort will have two main parts:

- Adapting your UI to take advantage of new Windows UI capabilities and design guidelines. Although you can reuse your design, you will typically rewrite most or all of your XAML code.
- Moving from the Silverlight APIs called in your code-behind files to the corresponding Windows Runtime APIs. Depending on your app, you may be able to port most of your code without change but you will typically need to rewrite 10% to 30% of it.

Comment: no sir think u misunderstood , i am asking that can i convert my windows phone apps to windows 8 app store apps

Comment: I would just add that not only the .NET frameworks are different but also the XAML stacks are different. The phone is based on Silverlight and Windows 8 WinRT-XAML/Jupiter is a native (non-.NET) WinRT library which uses a slightly different dialect of XAML, has different controls etc.